# Ansible: template error while templating string

Tags: python, ansible

On running the following task, its giving me the below error. I checked for the new line character and other syntax errors too but cant find one.
Is there any compatability issue or am I making any silly syntax issue? I'm running this task on a VM where pip is not installed ( & dont have permission to install)

```
   - name: Move old logs folder
     command: "mv {{ installed_dir }}/logs {{ installed_dir }}/logs_{{ old_version }}"  
     when: "groups['webservice'] | select('search','perfolab') | list"
```

Error message:

```
fatal: [myserver.dm.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'groups['webservice'] | select('search','perfolab') | list' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'select'. String: {% if groups['webservice'] | select('search','perfolab') | list %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/mylon/ansible-dep/webservice.yml': line 21, column 4, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - name: Move old logs folder\n     ^ here\n"}
```

Ansible version - ansible 2.6.4
python version = 2.6.6

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `selectattr` and not select

http://www.oznetnerd.com/jinja2-selectattr-filter/

Comment: THank you :) Does it need any specific Ansible version